# How can I permanently enable line numbers in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I permanently enable line numbers in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: why don't all IDE's have the default to "yes show line numbers", how do you debug anythign without using line numbers ?

Comment: Most IDE's have the line number where your mouse cursor is in the status bar, but that's not too useful. Normally there is line numbers in stack traces right? In VIM you can jump to line numbers <line number>G, and Sublime Text, Ctrl+g (type in line number). What's the benifit of line numbers if you can jump straight where you want to go?

Comment: What I like the most about the line number column is that it provides an easy hit area for selecting multiple lines without having to fiddle with exact cursor placement.

Comment: @NimChimpsky Well error messages (and the stack trace) in IntelliJ are links to the line of the code the error occurs on, so it's not too bad.

Comment: I also can't imagine people working without line numbers switched on. And never the less you might possibly don't need it because you just click on links in stacktraces. It gives you orientation in the code and might also be usefull if you talk to someone else about fragments of it.

Comment: All of you talking about clicking on stack traces are assuming that the stack trace being debugged is generated in the IDE. This is almost never the case in a real world scenario. You get a stack trace from a client and then you need to track it down.

Comment: @nullpointer: There never will. Looks like the user who asked the question has been deleted.

Comment: @Dan IntelliJ these days allows for analyzing an external stacktrace which makes lines into known code clickable.

Answer (score 1409):

### IntelliJ 14.X Onwards

From version 14.0 onwards, the path to the setting dialog is slightly different, a **General** submenu has been added between **Editor** and **Appearance** as shown below

[image]

### IntelliJ 8.1.2 - 13.X

From IntelliJ 8.1.2 onwards, this option is in **File | Settings**<sup>1</sup>. Within the **IDE Settings** section of that dialog, you'll find it under **Editor | Appearance.**

1. On a Mac, these are named **IntelliJ IDEA | Preferences...**

[image]

Comment: Cntrl + Shift + a --- Then type in "show line numbers".  I use cntrl+shift+a for finding most menu stuff.

Comment: For the Mac new-schoolers, Android Studio > Preferences > Editor > Appearance > Show line numbers

Comment: File | Settings | Editor | Appearance is where to find it in Android Studio, too (for obvious reasons?).

Comment: Confirmed: It's in the same place in Android Studio 0.8.2, too.

Comment: And if you don't like the Line Number color (used to be angry red) you can change that under Color & Fonts : General : Line Number

Comment: Even faster: 
press SHIFT-SHIFT;  
type 'line number';  
the option shows in the menu and press ENTER to enable/disable; 
Et voila ;)

Comment: It's still there (see IntelliJ 14.X) in IntelliJ IDEA 15 EAP.

Comment: Still the same place in version 15.0... :-)

Comment: NOT there in IntelliJ 2016.x :(

The Shift-Shift workaround still works though.

Comment: @csvan it's still there in IntelliJ 2016.1.1 under the appearance menu

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+A on windows only activates it in the current editor for the current session. SHIFT+SHIFT(as in the comment earlier and another answer) is permanent.

Comment: An important note: if you want to permanently enable line numbers for all future projects, you should make sure you're editing the `Default Settings`. You can access these from the `File` menu just below `Settings`, or when all projects are closed.

Answer (score 382):

The question is obviously well answered already, but since IJ 13 you can enable line numbers in 2 seconds flat:

1. Press <kbd>shift</kbd> twice
2. Type "line number"
3. The option shows in the menu and press <kbd>enter</kbd> to enable/disable.

[image]

Et voila ;)

Comment: As @user3218743 said, turning line numbers on this way is TEMPORARY. This is not the optimal solution.

Comment: In what way is it temporary?

Comment: if you start IJ and have line numbers disabled, run the instruction to enable it, then restart IJ, then the line numbers are disabled again ...

Comment: @user3218743 and @SamuelKerrien It depends on which of the one of the `show line number`s you select. There is one which turns it on/off temporary and one which changes settings (with an on/off toggle at end of line)

Comment: It doesn't work for me in Idea 2016, for some reason (Shift+Shift) :(

Comment: @manuna: just for clarity, you have to press *and release* `Shift` **two times consequently**, something like a "double click". Not hold the both `Shift`s at the same time :)

Comment: @HonzaZidek : thanks, I did hold two Shifts at the same time :)

Comment: Shift then Shift should surely be written Shift, Shift not Shift+Shift.

Comment: This worked for me to enable line numbers in active view editor configurations which by default is disabled for large files

Answer (score 111):

NOT a solution, rather a **TEMPORARY** solution which only works only for the current editor and current session:

Simply **right click** on the place where the line-numbers should be, and there you'll see a small menu.

then, mark the "Show Line Numbers" option.

[image]

Please note that this only works on a per-file basis, however.  Enjoy.

Comment: This is the most temporary way of turning line numbers on. The top answer is the proper way to do this so it sticks.

Comment: Only the current editor and current session. Removed on restarting android studio and does not show in any other windows.

Comment: This does **not** answer the question! *How can I **permanently** enable line numbers in IntelliJ IDEA?*

Comment: If you are aware that your post does not answer the question, I think it should have been posted as a comment only, not as an answer.

Answer (score 96):

In Intellij 13 the layout has changed, the Settings button can only be found in File -> Settings and not in the toolbars, and from there you follow the same steps: Editor -> Appearance -> Show line numbers, or search for Line numbers in the Settings search input.[image: Intellij Settings search for line numbers]

Comment: In Intellij 14 it's now File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance -> Show line numbers. Or Search for "Line Numbers".

Answer (score 77):

## **Android Studio 1.3.2 and on, IntelliJ 15 and on**

**Global configuration**

File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance -> Show line numbers

[image]

---

**Current editor configuration**

*First way:* View -> Active Editor -> Show Line Numbers (this option will only be available if you previously have clicked into a file of the active editor)

*Second way:* Right click on the small area between the project's structure and the active editor (that is, the one that you can set breakpoints) -> Show Line Numbers.
[image]

Answer (score 53):

**For InteliJ IDEA 11.0 and above**
Goto **File** --> **Settings** in the Settings window **Editor** --> **Appearance**
and tick Show line numbers check box.

[image]

Comment: This exact answer has [already been posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/912112/447356) two and half years ago by Don.

Comment: I looked again in the posts. They are the same, the slight difference does not justify new answer you could add comment on the existing answer saying something like "it also exist in version 11" and maybe explain this slight difference.

Answer (score 33):

IntelliJ 14 (Ubuntu):

See: [how-do-i-turn-on-line-numbers-permanently-in-intellij-14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27032622/how-do-i-turn-on-line-numbers-permanently-in-intellij-14)

Permanently:

File > Settings > Editor > General > Appearance > show line numbers

[image: Editor]

For current Editor:

View > Active Editor > Show Line Numbers

[image: Menu]

Answer (score 31):

### IntelliJ IDEA 15

#### 5 approaches

---

#### Global change

1. File > Settings... > Editor > General > Appearance > Show line numbers

   [image: show line numbers]
2. Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> **twice** > write "line numbers" > Show Line Numbers (that one that has the toggle) > change the toggle to ON

   [image: shift shift]

---

#### Change for the Active Editor

1. Right click on the left side bar > Show Line Numbers

   [image: right click]
2. Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> **twice** > write "line" > Show Line Numbers (the line doesn't have the toggle)

   [image: shift shift line]
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > write "Show line" > Active Editor: Show Line Numbers > change the toggle to ON

   [image: Ctrl Shift A]

Comment: Casper LI mentioned that **Android Studio 1.5.1** is similar with IntelliJ IDEA 15 regarding the line numbers.

Answer (score 23):

Ok in intelliJ 14 Ultimate using the Mac version this is it.

> IntelliJ Idea > Preferences > Editor > General > Appearance > Show Line Numbers

Comment: For those who have been struggling on Mac like I was to find this, don't be tricked by the "Appearance & Behavior" Tab, Like @Shawn said, it is under the editor tab, there are multiple levels with name appearance. Also Make sure you are looking at the settings under preferences.

Comment: @Unome Not only Mac, Windows too.

Answer (score 20):

On IntelliJ 12 on MAC OSX, I had a hard time finding it. The search wouldn't show me the way for some reason. Go to Preferences and under IDE Settings, Editor, Appearance and select 'Show line numbers'

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Android Studio

Go to **Android Studio** => **Preferences** => **Editor** => **General** => **Appearance** => set Checked "**Show line numbers**"

[image]

Answer (score 15):

I just hit this with IdeaVim plugin installed, where even if I set `Show Line Numbers`, it continued to revert to hiding them.

The (forehead-slapping-worthy) solution was:

```
:set nu
```

Answer (score 14):

I add this response for **IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2 - Ultimate**.

**Using menu**

*IntelliJ Idea > Preferences > Editor > General > Appearance > Show Line Numbers*

[image]

**Using Shortcuts - First way**

For Windows : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>
For Mac : <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>

[image]

**Using Shortcuts - Seconde way**

Touch <kbd>Shift</kbd> twice

[image]

These three methods exist since the last 4 versions of Intellij and I think they remain valid for a long time.

Answer (score 13):

**1st way:** Go to View => Active Editor => show line numbers

[image]

**2nd way** Go to Android Studio => Preferences => Editor=> Appearance => set Checked "Show Line Numbers"

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 12):

For 9.0.4

File > Settings

In the tree view group

------------IDE Settings ---------

Click the Editor [+]

Select Appearance... Its there.

Answer (score 10):

On Mac Intellij 12.1.2 there is no File-Settings:

There is an application-name menu item to the left of "File" with a "preferences" menu item:

[image: Choosing "Preferences" on the Mac.]

and within that is the "Settings" dialog shown by the Windows Intellij.

Answer (score 10):

In IntelliJ 14 it has moved again somewhat down the menu.

Now we have it unter `Editor -> General -> Appearance`

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Just an update for ***Android Studio 1.5.1*** on Windows:

Go to **File** -> **Settings** -> follow picture
[image]

Answer (score 7):

On **`IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.2`**

Go to **Settings > Editor > General > Appearance** 
then check the Show Line number option

[image]

Comment: Is 'Settings' in IDEA 2016.1.2 called 'preferences'?  I'm new to IntelliJ, so I don't want to edit that in this Answer before asking...

Comment: @cellepo Menu File > Settings

Answer (score 6):

IntelliJ 2019 community edition has line number by default.  If you want to show or hide line numbers, go to the following settings to change the appearance.

go to → File → Setting → Editor → General → Appearance → [Check] Show line numbers

[image: show_line_numbers]

Comment: in OSX this is under the "IntelliJ IDEA" menu not the file menu.

Answer (score 5):

For IntelliJ 20.1 or above, on Mac OSX:

**IntelliJ IDEA -> Editor -> General ->  Appearance -> Show line numbers**

**Point to be noted:**  Always look for `Editor`

[image]

For shortcut:

⌘ + ⇧ + A (command + shift + A)

type [image]

and click on the pop up to turn on `Show line numbers` and you are good to go.