# How do I turn on line numbers permanently in IntelliJ 14?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

How do I permanently turn on line numbers in IntelliJ IDEA 14?  This post is outdated: [how-can-i-permanently-have-line-numbers-in-intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751/how-can-i-permanently-have-line-numbers-in-intellij/27032572#27032572)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Permanently (Ubuntu):

File > Settings > Editor > General > Appearance > Show Line Numbers

[image]

For just the current editor:
View > Active Editor > Show Line Numbers

[image]

Comment: The process is basically the same for the Windows version of Intellij IDEA as well.

Answer (score 19):

You can do it even faster, using the Search Everywhere tool (press Shift twice): type "Show Line Numbers" (or even "line") and the top hit is the switch for permanent line numbers.
[image: Enable Line Numbers]

There are 2 switches for line numbers, one that has a On/Off switch and works globally, and one without the switch - for the current file. And one more for the Active Editor (current file).

[image]

Comment: this should be the accepted answer :)

Comment: see below for a solution that works permanently, not just for the current file

Comment: this works globally and permanently too.

Answer (score 4):

Go to *Settings/Editor/General/Appearance* and enable *Show line numbers* to permanently show line numbers for all editors.

The solution with *View > Active Editor > Show Line Numbers* seems to work only for the active editor (when you close the current tab or open a new file you have to enable it again).

Answer (score 2):

Go to *Preferences > Editor > Appearance*, and select the *Show line numbers* check box.

It will turn on the line numbers permanently.

Comment: This is the only answer for Updated Android Studio

Answer (score 2):

Just right click and enable Lines in Windows.
For more info [check this link.](http://code2care.org/pages/enable-line-numbers-in-intellij-android-studio-for-all-files/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.3

File > Settings > Editor > General > Appearance > Show Line Numbers

[image: IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.3]

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 1.3.2 (a variety of IntelliJ Idea) you can find the "Show line numbers" checkbox under:

Android Studio > Preferences > Editor > General > Appearance

Or, if you type "line numbers" into the main search box you'll be presented with a switch you can set right there.