# How to show line numbers in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm posting a quick reference for "How can I show line numbers in Android Studio?" See answer below.

NOTE: This question has been marked as a duplicate because Android Studio is based on [IntelliJ](http://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2013/05/15/intellij-idea-is-the-base-for-android-studio-the-new-ide-for-android-developers/). In future, if you have a similar question, it's probably worth looking for the IntelliJ setting.

Comment: @Sumurai8. As an Android newbie, I had forgotten Android Studio is based on IntelliJ. I didn't think to look for IntelliJ settings and googled for Android studio. Very little was returned. I will keep the post here to help other newbies and have updated the question with a note to point others in the right direction for similar queries. Thanks

Answer (score 199, accepted):

**In Windows**

1.Press `Ctrl+Shift+A`

[image]
2.Input following string: "show line numbers"

[image]
And you will see the setting, this method can find all the settings easily!

**MAC**

1.Press `Command+Shift+A`
2.Input following string: "show line numbers"

and following same flow of android studio.

Comment: Despite answering my own question, marking this as the answer as it's the fastest way to get the right result.

Comment: I have found that, after doing this, my line numbers get turned off again. There is a permanent solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/912112/1617737 .

Comment: it works in linux version also

Comment: It think by default after installing Android Studio, line numbers should be shown.

Answer (score 44):

It's simple. Just Right click in left side of Workspace area and choose `Show line number`.

[image]

Comment: This shows the line numbers. But only for the current file. If you need to show it to all files, then you should use @HockeyJ's solution below!

Answer (score 38):

1. Go to File > Settings
2. In the dialog, select 'Editor', then the sub-option for 'General', and then the sub-option  for 'Appearance'.
3. Select 'Show line numbers' as shown below.
4. Click Ok.

[image]

[Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJJ9MzwlSIM)

**UPDATE** The location for this setting has been changed to Editor -> General -> Appearance.

Comment: Really makes you wonder why this isn't enabled by default...

Comment: I think from v2.3. This is the default behaviour. @RobertOliveira